# Could someone explain what my code does/how to fix it(search node in bst)?

Tags: c, recursion, data-structures, binary-search-tree

The point of this function was to search for a node and return 0 if not found and 1 if found. From some testing, it looks like even if it is found, it still returns 0 every time unless the node is root. Can someone explain why my code is wrong?

In main I set a variable = search and if variable = 1, print present and if variable = 0, print absent.

What I tested it with was a bst of 3 and 4. I tested the bst and know it is set up correctly

if I search for 3, counter returns 1 and main prints present.
if I search for 4, What I think happens is it still goes to the if (root->data == value) statement and sets counter to 1 and returns it. However, instead of going back to main it then goes to the return counter in the bottom (which is equal to 0) and returns that to main making it print absent even though it's there. Could somebody walk me step by step exactly what is happening in this code and why, and how I would make it return 1 back to main?

```
  int search(struct Node* root, int value){
    int counter = 0;
    if (root->data == value){
            counter = 1;
            return counter;
}       if (root == NULL){
            return counter;
}
    if (value < root-> data){
             search(root->left, value);
}
    else if (value > root->data){
            search(root->right, value);
}

    return counter;
}
```

EDIT: I also tried turning it into a void function and instead of returning, it prints "present" if node is found. Is there a way to make it only print absent once using this way though?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `search()` on a root node, if the desired value is not in the root but is in the right subtree, then `search(root->right, value)` should return 1. But even if it does so, your function will still return 0. (Check this: starting from the line where `search(root->right, value)` is called, assume that returns 1 and trace through the rest of your function, and you'll see that it returns 0.)

In order to fix this, you need to check the return value from `search(root->right, value)`, and if it's 1 (indicating that the value was found in the right subtree), your function will need to behave accordingly. Similarly with the return value from `search(root->left, value)`.

Answer (score 0):

The general form of a BST search algorithm is:

```
boolean search (node, value) {
    if node == null return false
    if value == node.data return true
    if (value < node.data)
        return search(root.left, value)
    return search(root.right, value)
}
```